# Optional list param coming in as instantiated when not passed in query string in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-1.0

My Web API method looks like the following:

```
[HttpGet]
public IList<Product> Get(List<int> categoryIds = null)
{
    IList<Product> prods = _productService.GetProducts(categoryIds);
    return prods;
}
```

How come when I simple just called api/products without query string params category Ids doesn't come in as null? Instead it has a count of 0

Comment: there is no parameter called "category Ids" in your code.  There is, however, one called "categoryIds"

Comment: @SamIam Sorry about that, copied and pasted and forgot to change it. So do you know why categoryIds doesn't stay null when nothing is passed in the url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object expected by the action (`List<int> categoryIds`) is instantiated using its default constructor **and then** model binding looks for matches in the URL to populate it. As model binding doesn't find any params to further put in the `List<int>`, it is just newed up.

From [MVC Model Binding](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/models/model-binding.html):

> In order for binding to happen the class must have a public default constructor and member to be bound must be public writable properties. When model binding happens the class will only be instantiated using the public default constructor, then the properties can be set.
>
> For those types such as 'Collection' types, model binding looks for matches to *parameter_name[index]* or just *[index]*.

You can include the list in a complex object and accept the object in the action:

```
public class Request
{
    public List<int> categoryIds { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your controller action:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<int> Get(Request request)
    {
        return request.categoryIds;
    }
}
```

Then your request will be:

```
/api/values?categoryIds[0]=0&categoryIds[1]=1
```

Comment: So you saying it is normal? And I should just check .Any if I need to know if any items were sent or not?

Comment: Yes, the model binder will always new up the action parameter using the default constructor. You can include the list in a complex object as shown in the updated answer.